# Normalize company names in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am looking to normalize some company names by removing INC, Co or Corp from the column. I have been having issues using reg_replace as it removes inc from other words as well. For example "Finch Insurance" or "Colorado Mining" will drop to "Fh Insurance or "lorado Mining".

Here is an example of what I am using now normalize the name

```
Update table SET AccountName = reg_replace(AccountName,'INC','',TRUE,3,3);
```

Comment: This isn't a normalization issue/question. What you need is a regex expression that only selects the INC CO or CORP if they are "words". IOW, there is some separation character before and after. Possible characters would include comma, space, tab, end of line, etc. Look at [MySQL RegEx Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html) and [MySQL RegEx Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#regexp-syntax).

Comment: I am having issues running the regex functions as it states they do not exist even thought I have MySQL version 8. The reg_replace function above was ran as a custom function

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but it should work to locate the terms you mentioned.

```
(^[.]*)(\s|\.|\,)(CORP|corp|Corp|INC|Inc|inc|CO|Co|co)(\s|\.|\,|$)
```